# azcopy from Google Cloud to Azure just hangs

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azcopy

I am trying to use azcopy to copy from Google Cloud to Azure.
I'm following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-google-cloud) and I can see in the logs generated that the connectivity to GCP seems fine, the SAS token is fine and it creates the container fine (see it appear in Azure Storage Explorer) but then it just hangs. Output is:

```
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Authenticating to source using GoogleAppCredentials
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support
```

If I look at the log it shows:

```
2022/06/01 07:43:25 AzcopyVersion  10.15.0
2022/06/01 07:43:25 OS-Environment  windows
2022/06/01 07:43:25 OS-Architecture  amd64
2022/06/01 07:43:25 Log times are in UTC. Local time is 1 Jun 2022 08:43:25
2022/06/01 07:43:25 ISO 8601 START TIME: to copy files that changed before or after this job started, use the parameter --include-before=2022-06-01T07:43:20Z or --include-after=2022-06-01T07:43:20Z
2022/06/01 07:43:25 Authenticating to source using GoogleAppCredentials
2022/06/01 07:43:26 Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support
```

As I say, no errors around SAS token being out of date, or can't find the GCP credentials, or anything like that.
It just hangs.
It does this if I try and copy a single named file or a recursive directory copy. Anything.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

•   I would suggest you to please check the logs of these AzCopy transactions for more details on this scenario. `To collect the logs and analyze them, you will have to check the logs stored in ‘%USERPROFILE%\.azcopy’ directory on Windows`. AzCopy creates log and plan files for every job, so you will have to investigate and troubleshoot any potential problems regarding this scenario by analyzing them.

•   As you are **encountering hang issues with the AzCopy utility during a job execution for transferring files, it might be a network fluctuation issue, timeout issue or server busy issues**. Please do remember that `AzCopy retries upto 20 times in these cases and usually the retry process succeeds`. Try to look for the errors in the logs that are near **‘UPLOADFAILED, COPYFAILED, or DOWNLOADFAILED’**.

•   The following command will get all the errors with **‘UPLOADFAILED’** status from the concerned log file: -

```
   Select-String UPLOADFAILED .\<CONCERNEDLOGFILE GUID>.log
```

**To show the jobs by status relating to the job ID, kindly execute the below command: -**

```
  azcopy jobs show <job-id> --with-status=Failed
```

•   Execute the AzCopy job execution command from your local system with **‘--no-check-certificate’ argument** which will **ensure that there are no certificate checks for the system certificates at the receiving end**. Ensure that the `root certificates for the network client device or software are correctly installed on your local system as they are the only ones to block your jobs while transferring files from on-premises to Azure`.

Also, `once the job starts initially without any parameters, then when it hangs, just press CTRL+C to kill the process and then immediately check the logs in AzCopy as well as in the event viewer for any system issues. It will help you know the exact issue regarding this. It really shows why the process failed and got hung`.

For more information, kindly refer to the documentation link below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-configure***

***https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/517***

Answer (score 1):

Frustratingly, having many calls with Microsoft support, on demoing this to another person the exact same command with exact same SAS token etc that was previously failing just started to work.
I hate problems that 'fix themselves' as it means it will likely occur again.

Thanks to KartikBhiwapurkar-MT for a detailed response too.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the exact same hanging behavior and output, and there were no azcopy logs generated.

For me, the issue was I was authenticated with a GCP service account that didn't have access to the source files in GCP. I resolved the issue by authenticating with a service account that did in fact have access.

This isn't necessarily your issue - I suspect there are other errors that could cause this behavior - but it's something to check.